# How do I join the column even if if it's null? in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a query that displays questions under a subcategory and more questions under a category since there's a subcategory under a category. Here's my code

```
SELECT 
   a.* 
FROM question a 
LEFT JOIN category b on a.question_subcat = b.category_id 
WHERE b.parentcategoryid  = $question
```

How do I include to display the question_subcat with null values and not just the one with value? Since not all my questions have to be under a subcategory, it can be just under a category without being under in any subcategory which makes it null. How do I display it?

Comment: Try moving `b.parentcategoryid  = $question` to the `ON` clause.

Comment: This can be complex, but extremely flexible and fast (query performance) for nested data sets. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I don't understand can you please reply in code format sir? @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: What is $question containing: the sub or the main category id.
Why do you store the sub category id in `question.question_subcat` - from my point of view questions should only have a parentcategory_id

Comment: `LEFT JOIN category b on a.question_subcat = b.category_id AND b.parentcategoryid  = $question`. This returns *all* questions regardless of the existence or not of a correlated `category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left outer join should give you exactly what you are asking for! If you remove the WHERE condition all your questions where `question_subcat` is null will appear.

Anyhow I do not completely understand your requirement, but you need to filter on the parent table or provide an alternative where condition.

Just think about: left out join returns all table rows of a and rows of table b only where they exist (meaning b.* is null) - no question missing. But your where filters b.parentcategoryid with `$question` => b.parentcatoryid is null if not found => where filter kicks it out.